# Зашифровать картинку

Tags: java

Есть некое изображение в формате jpg. Получаем массив байт:

```
public byte[] extractBytes (String ImageName) throws IOException {
    // open image
    File imgPath = new File(ImageName);
    BufferedImage bufferedImage = ImageIO.read(imgPath);

    // get DataBufferBytes from Raster
    WritableRaster raster = bufferedImage.getRaster();
    DataBufferByte data   = (DataBufferByte) raster.getDataBuffer();

    return ( data.getData() );
}
```

Далее, шифруем этот массив с помощью алгоритма DES (http://j2w.blogspot.com.by/2008/01/des-java.html) и нужно создать новую картинку из зашифрованных байт

```
public void createImg(byte[] arr)
{
    try {
        File myNewJPegFile = new File("code.jpg");
        BufferedImage bufferedImage = ImageIO.read(new ByteArrayInputStream(arr));
        ImageIO.write(bufferedImage, "jpg", myNewJPegFile);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Но я получаю ошибку

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: image == null!

В строке `ImageIO.write(bufferedImage, "jpg", myNewJPegFile);`.

В чем проблема?

Comment: Очевидно, что метод read() возвращает null. Скорее всего это происходит во внутреннем методе `BufferedImage read(ImageInputStream stream)` класса ImageIO в строке `if (!iter.hasNext()) {
            return null;
        }`. Попробуйте посмотреть дебаггером в какой момент в данном классе возвращается null.

Comment: Если используете ImageIO.read() для чтения, логично также использовать ImageIO.write() для записи в массив через поток. Иначе можно нарушить формат.

Answer (score 3):

Если нужно зашифровать только графическую часть, то можно достать RGB массив из картинки. Ниже приведен пример преобразования графической части.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
{
    if (args.length != 2)
        System.exit(1);

    File srcFile = new File(args[0]);
    File dstFile = new File(args[1]);

    if (!srcFile.exists())
        System.exit(2);

    String fileExt = getFileExt(dstFile.getName());
    if (fileExt == null)
        System.exit(3);

    System.out.println("Loading file at " + srcFile.getAbsolutePath());
    BufferedImage srcImage = ImageIO.read(srcFile);
    final int w = srcImage.getWidth();
    final int h = srcImage.getHeight();
    int[] rgb = srcImage.getRGB(0, 0, w, h, null, 0, w);

    System.out.println("Applying cipher");
    applyCipher(rgb);

    System.out.println("Saving file at " + dstFile.getAbsolutePath());
    BufferedImage dstImage = new BufferedImage(w, h, srcImage.getType());
    dstImage.setRGB(0, 0, w, h, rgb, 0, w);
    ImageIO.write(dstImage, fileExt, dstFile);
}

public static void applyCipher(int[] rgb)
{
    Random rnd = new Random();

    for(int i=0; i < rgb.length; i++)
    {
        rgb[i] = rgb[i] ^ rnd.nextInt();
    }
}

public static String getFileExt(String filename)
{
    int dotIndex = filename.lastIndexOf('.');
    if (dotIndex == -1)
        return null;
    return filename.substring(dotIndex+1);
}
```

Comment: Стоит обратить внимание на то, что при сохранении в jpg формате может происходить компрессия с потерей информации.